# addgroup and chown in Ubuntu

Tags: chown

I created a new group with this command: `sudo addgroup user123`
assign few users to user123 group: `sudo usermod -aG user123 sam`
created a shared directory named user123 but when I try to change directory ownership to user123, I got this error message: `chown : invalid user`

```
sudo chown user123:user123 user123
```

I can see user123 in `/etc/group` with a group ID. What went wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You added a group named `user123` yet you try to change ownership not only to that group, but also to a user `user123`. Alas, that user does not exist, hence the error message.

Comment: Thank you! You are right, the group created user123 is not a user, was just a shared directory.